# def fileName = new File(directoryName+"XYZ.md") does not work on cloud environment

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Anybody knows why this `File file = new File(directotyName+"xyz.md")` does not work on cloud environment. I tried a lot but no clue, I have been reading articles and tried lot for things but it didn't work either.

My scenario goes like this,

I'm developing a plugin where in one groovy class it creates a new file at /build/someFolder/xyz.md but for some reason it works at local but when I release the plugin to a repository and try to use it in some project and try to run the build and deploy the project using Jenkins on cloud linux based environment it just fails,

I tried with,
1) Files.write(/build/someFolder/xyz.md, object of iterable interface)

and some other ways as well but its failing.

Does anyone has any idea how do I overcome this problem.

Comment: "Failing"... How? What error is it raising? Does `/build/` exist on the remote machine? Does the user running Jenkins have permissions to write to that directory if it exists?

Comment: File system access in a cloud environment usually spells trouble. The whole idea behind the cloud was that it's not really running on a computer, but rather in the abstract concept of "cloud".

Comment: Actually the code before creating a file is creation of directory structure so for that I m using  projectDir + File.separator +"build"+ File.separator+"generateReleaseReport" and creating a folder, I have put the logs and it says it could create a folder and then for fie creation in this folder just fails

Comment: I tried to print the distsDir and it gives me a result as /var/jenkins/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Pipeline/jobs/project_name/jobs/deploy/workspace/build/distributions so from this I can say yes build exists

Comment: "just fails" is extremely vague. Do you get an exception? Does it hang? What happens?

Comment: I have started the server in debug mode, lets see what it says but for creating a file as a plugin I was not getting any errors but the project which implements the plugin is throwing an error of FileNotFoundException which is obvious as the plugin is failing to create it so the project not getting it

Comment: @tyro : one possible reason may be for the file not found is permissions to access the directory/files.

Comment: Hi I tried, with creating a directory  ""+buildDir+SomeFolder and it worked, Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your issue is that system Groovy script on Jenkins runs on 'master' node even that your pipeline runs on a node.

A workaround I'm using for such cases is to run a shell script instead, because it runs on the node.

Comment: Thanks yorammi for the explanation